# How to set the property of an item with the index?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

According to Vue's official [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html) you can set an item with the index like this:

```
example.items[indexOfItem] = newValue // the value won't change
example.items.splice(indexOfItem, 1, newValue) // it will change here
```

How to use the `splice` technique if I want to set the item's property like this:

```
example.items[indexOfItem].property = newValue
```

Example input:

```
example.items = [
  { property: 'a' },
  { property: 'b' }
]
```

Comment: Can you share your `items` array?

Comment: @HassanImam I updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you.

```js
var items = [
  { property: 'a' },
  { property: 'b' }
];
var indexOfItem = 1;
var newValue = {property:'c'};
items.splice(indexOfItem ,1, newValue);
console.log(items);
```

Comment: You're a genius!